# Embed Tenor link with discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, gif

How do I get the direct `.gif` link from a tenor shareable view link? Because I want a user to be able to give the bot a shareable view link, which would then be put into an embed. If I need to use the tenor API for that could anyone show me how?

```py
@client.command()
async def gifembed(ctx, link):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Here's your embed", color=0xb0ff70)
    embed.set_image(url=f"{link}")
    await ctx.respond(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Python's `requests` module to get the web page from the sharable view link. Then you can scan the page for the direct `.gif` link and send that to your bot users.

Here is an example test code to get the direct `.gif` URL from the view link:

```py
import requests
import re
 
def find_gif_url(string):
    # Regex to find the URL on the c.tenor.com domain that ends with .gif
    regex = r"(?i)\b((https?://c[.]tenor[.]com/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))[.]gif)"
    return re.findall(regex, string)[0][0]

view_url = 'https://tenor.com/view/link-gif-6068206'

# Get the page content
r = requests.get(view_url)
# Find the URL of the gif
gif_url = find_gif_url(r.text)
print(gif_url)
```

So, you could pack that into a nice function like such:

```py
def get_gif_url(view_url):

    # Get the page content
    page_content = requests.get(view_url).text

    # Regex to find the URL on the c.tenor.com domain that ends with .gif
    regex = r"(?i)\b((https?://c[.]tenor[.]com/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))[.]gif)"

    # Find and return the first match
    return re.findall(regex, page_content)[0][0]
```

From what I've seen by taking a look at tenor's website, the direct `.gif` link always seems to be the first URL that points to `c.tenor.com` ending in `.gif`, forgive me if I'm mistaken.

Hope this helps, cheers!